# How to load data from xml with condition?

Tags: xml, datatable

How can I load data from an xml file into a DataTable with a condition?

Comment: **XPath** allows you to do that, but please provide more details.

Comment: want to fill the data into datatable from xml file with certain condition?

Comment: But what is the condition, and what does your XML file look like ? Please edit your original post with that information.

Comment: Load the data, filter it out, put it in your database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply a condition when loading the data.

You can easily load an XML file into a DataTable, and then either

- create a DataView over the DataTable to show you only the rows you're interested in
- loop over the DataTable and delete out the unwanted rows

Marc

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way to do this is to filter the data after reading it into a `DataTable`.  But that approach may not be ideal if, for instance, the XML file is extremely large and the set of filtered rows is small:  you incur the time and space costs of allocating, processing, and destroying a very large number of objects in order to get a small number of them.

There's a way around this, but it's not trivial:  subclass `XmlReader`.  Do the filtering in the subclass as it's reading the XML, returning only nodes that meet your filtering criteria to the caller of the `Read()` method.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973822.aspx) describes how to write an `XmlReader` that allows (say) `XmlDocument` to read .INI files as though they were XML documents.  It's actually easier to write a filtering `XmlReader`, as you don't have to deal with all of the parsing issues that are described in this article - you just have your `XmlReader` subclass instantiate its own `XmlReader`, and then return (or don't) nodes that it reads.